# Get absolute T-SQL row number where filtering does not affect row number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Currently, I have a sql script which grabs a couple hundred thousand records and I want to page through the data.

Paging works for the most part but my problem is when filtering my results from a subquery which gets the row number, the row number effectively always starts at 1 when what I want it to do is return the row number it was assigned during the sub-query (if that makes sense).

What I have is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT --TOP(@End-@Start)
        EF.FulfillmentID
        ,COALESCE(GEN.GroupID, GEL.GroupID) AS GroupID
        ,COALESCE(GEN.GroupName, GEL.GroupName) AS GroupName
        ,EF.PlanEnrollmentID
        ,EF.PlanElectionID
        ,COALESCE(EE2.EmployeeID, EE.EmployeeID) AS EmployeeID
        ,COALESCE(EE2.FirstName, EE.FirstName) AS FirstName
        ,COALESCE(EE2.LastName, EE.LastName) AS LastName
        ,COALESCE(EPE2.BeginDate, EPE.EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
        ,COALESCE(EPE2.EndDate, EPE.TerminationDate) AS TerminationDate
        ,COALESCE(CPEN.CarrierProductID, CPEL.CarrierProductID) AS CarrierProductID
        ,COALESCE(CPEN.CarrierProductName, CPEL.CarrierProductName) AS CarrierProductName
        ,EF.FulFillmentTypeID
        ,FT.FulfillmentTypeDesc
        ,EF.FulfillmentComplete
        ,CAST(EF.RunFulfillment AS BIT) AS RunFulfillment
        ,CAST(@CanModify AS BIT) AS CanModify
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by EF.FulfillmentID) as Num
    FROM
        dbo.E_Fulfillment AS EF
        JOIN appconfig.FulfillmentTypes AS FT ON FT.FulfillmentTypeID=EF.FulFillmentTypeID
        JOIN(
            SELECT
                MAX(FulfillmentID) AS MaxFulfillmentID
            FROM
                dbo.E_Fulfillment
            GROUP BY
                COALESCE(PlanElectionID, PlanEnrollmentID)
            ) AS MX ON MX.MaxFulfillmentID=EF.FulfillmentID

        LEFT JOIN dbo.E_PlanEnrollment AS EPE ON EPE.PlanEnrollmentID=EF.PlanEnrollmentID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.GroupProductPlanOptions AS GPPOEN ON GPPOEN.GroupProductPlanOptionID=EPE.GroupProductPlanOptionID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.GroupProducts AS GPEN ON GPEN.GroupProductID=GPPOEN.GroupProductID
        LEFT JOIN ref.CarrierProducts AS CPEN ON CPEN.CarrierProductID=GPEN.CarrierProductID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Groups AS GEN ON GEN.GroupID=GPEN.GroupID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.E_Employees EE ON EE.EmployeeID=EPE.EmployeeID

        LEFT JOIN dbo.E_PlanElections AS EPE2 ON EPE2.PlanElectionID=EF.PlanElectionID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.GroupProductPlanOptions AS GPPOEL ON GPPOEL.GroupProductPlanOptionID=EPE2.GroupProductPlanOptionID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.GroupProducts AS GPEL ON GPEL.GroupProductID=GPPOEL.GroupProductID
        LEFT JOIN ref.CarrierProducts AS CPEL ON CPEL.CarrierProductID=GPEL.CarrierProductID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.Groups AS GEL ON GEL.GroupID=GPEL.GroupID
        LEFT JOIN dbo.E_Employees AS EE2 ON EE2.EmployeeID=EPE2.EmployeeID

    WHERE
        ((GEN.GroupID=@GroupID OR GEN.GroupID IS NULL)
        OR (EPE2.EmployeeID=@EmployeeID OR EPE2.EmployeeID IS NULL)
        OR (@GroupID IS NULL AND @EmployeeID IS NULL))
        AND FulfillmentID > @KeyIndex
        ) as MyDerivedTable

        where (MyDerivedTable.Num BETWEEN @Start AND @End)
        AND FulfillmentID > @KeyIndex
        order by FulfillmentID
```

So just to kind of describe what is going on, @Start, @End, and @KeyIndex are input parameters.

`@Start/@End` = Start/End At Row (Which works just fine; starts and ends where I need it to be if @KeyIndex is 0)

@KeyIndex = Start where PrimaryKey > @KeyIndex (which is where the row number becomes an issue).

I think what may be going on is that records before @KeyIndex are not being calculated but I cannot see why that is since the subquery is what holds the row number and I assume it's processed prior to the parent query finishing ?

```
where (MyDerivedTable.Num BETWEEN @Start AND @End)
AND FulfillmentID > @KeyIndex
order by FulfillmentID
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You do know `AND FulfillmentID > @KeyIndex` is also in your subquery?

Records before @KeyIndex are not being calculated because you told it not to process those records.

Comment: Yes, I do know that and it is intended. I want to be able to filter where FulfillmentID > @KeyIndex without affecting the row number -- which is precisely my issue.

Comment: No helping you.

Comment: If you aren't gong to help or post anything useful why post at all? I don't feel like my question is all that far-fetched at all .

Comment: I did post something useful.   You just don't understand it.   You came back with that is intended.

Comment: No, you didn't. You told me I had a statement in my query which I already knew considering I wrote it.

What would be helpful is telling me what the problem is with the statement -- not ask me if I know I had a certain statement.

Again, the AND FulfillmentID > @KeyIndex is intended. I want to filter by Fulfillment ID.

Comment: Do I have to spell it out?  You don't want the sub query to filter but you are filtering in the sub query.  If you did want the sub query to filter then there would be no purpose to the second where.

Comment: It doesn't sound like you understand my problem (and that may be at the fault of my explanation.).

Thanks anyway for your "help". Take care.